# Calculating eigenvalues of a large matrix takes a long time

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a tridiagonal matrix (1000×1000) with each element equal to $1$ except `{n, n} = 2`. It takes 8 hours to give me the eigenvalues?!!

Here is the code I used:

```
n=1000;

m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
    Band[{2, 2}, {n - 1, n - 1}] -> 2 , {1, 1} -> 2, {n, n} -> 
     2 , {1, n} -> 0, {n, 1} -> 0}, {n, n}];

N[Eigenvalues[m]];
```

Comment: Your matrix hasn't the form you are describing. Try `m//MatrixForm`

Comment: FWIW mma v9 actually throws a warning that clearly provides the answer to this question.  `...consider using N on the matrix ... `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you've written things, you're passing an **exact** matrix to `Eigenvalues` and then finding a numerical approximation afterwards, so *Mathematica* is trying to compute an exact answer algebraically. For a 1000 × 1000 matrix, this obviously takes a while. In order to get an answer more quickly, find the numerical approximation first and then find the eigenvalues, like so:

```
Eigenvalues[N[m]];
```

On my computer, this takes less than a second with the matrix specified.

Comment: It works, Thank you very much

Comment: Instead of using the default method, one can utilize the banded structure and use the following command: `Eigenvalues[N[m], Method -> "Banded"]`

Answer (score 5):

Use `N` on the matrix itself

```
n = 1000;
m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, 
    Band[{2, 2}, {n - 1, n - 1}] -> 2, {1, 1} -> 2, {n, n} -> 2, {1, n} -> 0, {n, 1} -> 0}, {n, n}];
AbsoluteTiming[Eigenvalues[N@m]]


 {0.489062, {3.99999, 3.99996, 3.99991, 3.99984, 3.99975, 3.99965, 3.99952, 3.99937, 3.9992,....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I got the result  with this message :                              Eigenvalues::arh: Because finding 500 out of the 500 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted. If fewer eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors would be sufficient, consider restricting this number using the second argument to Eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes it is.. Again, thank you very much Nasser!

Answer (score 5):

It is known that there are [closed forms for the eigenvalues of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2005/040903-7.pdf) like the one given in the OP:

```
n = 1000;
N[4 Sin[π Range[n]/(2 n + 2)]^2]
```

See the linked paper for more details, as well as closed forms for the eigenvalues of modified tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices.